# Libgdx ParticleEffect resize, scale?

Tags: libgdx

I am using particle editor for 3D effect. Created everything was ok, and added to my libgdx game. My probleme is the scale is very big .

How can I change the particles scale at runtime or other?

Searched a lot of here in SO, and I can not find an answer for the MODERN libgdx. I am using the LATEST. So those solutions not work at all...

Any help?

```
    targetMatrix
            .idt()
            .setToTranslation(astronaut.getPosition())
            .setToScaling(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f);
    effect.setTransform(targetMatrix);
```

but this is not working

my pfx file:

pastebin.com/yzCDQape

Comment: Hi lacas, instead of "modern" or "latest" a version number would be helpful I guess

Comment: gdxVersion = '1.9.5'

Comment: by the way I tried with latest 1.9.6 and the smae results:         targetMatrix
                .idt()
                .setToTranslation(astronaut.getPosition())
                .mul(new Matrix4().scl(0.01f))
        ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up uses the emitters theta and phivalues highmin and highmax. Thanks